# Sql group by, conversion

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two `bit` type columns in my sql table for the staff attendance, and the type of leave like `1 for Medical Leave or 2 for Paid Leave`,the values in it are like,

```
FirstHalfLeave   Type      SecondHalfLeave  Type
 ------------    ----       -------------   ----
      0(Absent)   1             1             2
      1(Present)  1             1             2
```

I need to sum these two fields to make it leave for a single day and I need to dislay the exact result like

```
  Type          Days
  ----         ------
MedicalLeave     0.5
PaidLeave        1.0
```

for this I tried like

```
select cast(
       sum(
             (
               CAST(StaffAttendance.FirstHalfStatus as Integer) + 
               CAST(StaffAttendance.SecondHalfStatus as integer)
             ) 
             / 2.0
       ) as float
   ) as TotalLeave
   ,case when StaffAttendance.FirstHalfLeaveType = 2 OR 
StaffAttendance.SecondHalfLeaveType=2 then 'Paid Leave'
   else 'Medical Leave'
   end as Status
from StaffAttendance
where MONTH(StaffAttendance.date)=MONTH(GetDate())
group by StaffAttendance.FirstHalfLeaveType,StaffAttendance.SecondHalfLeaveType
```

but its not grouping well, I dunno how to do this, can anyone help me here, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(sa.LeaveDays)/COUNT(sa.LeaveDays),sa.Status
FROM
    (
        SELECT CAST(FirstHalfStatus AS FlOAT) LeaveDays,CASE WHEN FirstHalfLeaveType=2 THEN 'Paid Leave' ELSE 'Medical Leave' END as Status,date
        FROM StaffAttendance        
        UNION ALL
        SELECT CAST(SecondHalfStatus AS FlOAT),CASE WHEN SecondHalfLeaveType=2 THEN 'Paid Leave' ELSE 'Medical Leave' END as Status,date
        FROM StaffAttendance
    ) AS sa
WHERE MONTH(sa.date)=MONTH(GetDate())   
GROUP BY sa.Status
```

Comment: Sometimes `SUM(sa.LeaveDays) / COUNT(sa.LeaveDays)` can also be shortened to `AVG(sa.LeaveDays)`. :)

Comment: @AndriyM 100% right. AVG() is shortened. But I've forgot to use that shortened. :)